# py2neo 2.0.4 remote connection refused

Tags: py2neo

looked into related questions and answers and can't find a solution for the 'connection refused' when trying to use py2neo 2.0.4.

Here the ipython session (python '2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]')

```
[1]: from py2neo import Graph, watch
[2]: watch('httpstream')
[3]: g = Graph('http://odroid:7474/db/data')
[4]: g.cypher.execute('match (y:Year) return y')

GET http://odroid:7474/db/data/
200 OK [699]
GET http://odroid:7474/
200 OK [94]
POST http://odroid:7474/db/data/transaction/commit [102]
200 OK [chunked]
GET http://0.0.0.0:7474/
! SocketError: Connection refused
```

The installed bin/cypher also fails.

Same on odroid (odroid-c1 arm quad core) works fine (even with the same url).

Other methods g.create(Node... ) work fine.

Comment: Which Neo4j version are you using?

Comment: It's neo4j community 2.1.6

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like correct behaviour and there's nothing obvious wrong with your code.

I'm not sure which version of Neo4j server you're using but you could try narrowing down the issue to either a problem in the driver or a problem in the server by using cURL against the REST interface directly. Complex network configurations (e.g. using a proxy) can also contribute to unexpected behaviours like this. Depending on your setup, you may want to try to eliminate that too.

If you can narrow this down to either a py2neo or Neo4j problem then your best bet is to raise an issue on the corresponding project on GitHub.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: Neo4j 2.1.6. Curl and other neo4j frameworks (e.g. neomodel) work fine. Maybe it's related to my Mac environment. I'll try to reproduce it on another Linux/Mac/Windows client.